# Apache Shiro - LDAP for Authentication and Properties/Ini for Authorization

Tags: apache, authentication, authorization, shiro, jdbcrealm

i´m trying to add some authentication and authorization functionality to my small web application. therefore i´m using apache shiro.

my plan: using an existing ldap server for user authentication and using a properties or ini file for authorization.

here´s a small example: 
user x wants to use the application
he enters his username and his password
the ldap server is used for authentication --> user + pwd correct?
if authentication is verified and correct, a properties file or ini file is used to check if the user is permitted, to start some functions inside the application.

i hope you know what i´m trying to do.

now i´m not sure how to implement this feature. is it enough to use an ini file or is it required to implement my own realm?! is there an example implementation?

i´m grateful for every information

and sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to implement a realm but this is not difficult. You just have to extend `JndiLdapRealm` and override the `queryForAuthorizationInfo` method.

This method returns an `AuthorizationInfo` interface type. In your case the easiest is to return  an instance of `SimpleAuthorizationInfo` which implements this interface.

You must initialize the `AuthorizationInfo` with the roles and/or permissions for the authenticated user. When this method is called, the user is already authenticated but not authorized.

Inside this method you can read the authorization information from any data source that you want, it can be a properties or ini file, properties associated with the user in the LDAP server, a database or anything that pleases you.

A realm implementation could be:

```
package example.shiro.realm.ldap;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.LdapContextFactory;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection;

public class JndiLdapAuthzRealm extends JndiLdapRealm {

    private List<String> getRoles(String userName) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        // TODO: get roles from data source and fill list
        roles.add("user");
        roles.add("admin");
        return roles;
    }

    private List<String> getPermissions(String userName) {
        List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();
        // TODO: get permissions from data source and fill list
        perms.add("myapp:run");
        perms.add("myapp:file:create");
        return perms;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals,
            LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        String userName = principals.getPrimaryPrincipal().toString();
        info.addRoles(getRoles(userName));
        info.addStringPermissions(getPermissions(userName));
        return info;
    }
}
```

In your case, rewrite the `getRoles` and `getPermissions` to get the roles and permissions for the authenticated user from the properties or ini file.

In `shiro.ini`:

```
[main]

ldapRealm = example.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapAuthzRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://192.168.0.10
```